# How do i extract values inside Elixir Map

Tags: elixir

Assuming I have this

```elixir
%{
  "contact_full_name" => ["Jane", "Joe", "Job"],
  "contact_mobile_number" => ["1234", "5678", "9012"],
  "contact_relationship" => ["sibling", "stuff", "stuff"]
}
```

How do I iterate through that map, getting 
   `"jane, 1234, sibling"`, `"Jone, "5678", "stuff"`, etc.

Tried using

```elixir
Enum.each(contact, fn {k, v} ->
  IO.puts("#{k} --> #{v}")
end)
```

but that produces

```
contact_full_name --> JaneJoeJob
contact_mobile_number --> 123456789012
contact_relationship --> siblingstuffstuff
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extract the map values with [`Map.values/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#values/1), and then zip the list values with [`Enum.zip/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#zip/1):

```elixir
contact_details = %{
  "contact_full_name"     => ["Jane", "Joe", "Job"],
  "contact_mobile_number" => ["1234", "5678", "9012"],
  "contact_relationship"  => ["sibling", "stuff", "stuff"]
}

contact_details |> Map.values() |> Enum.zip()
```

This yields:

```elixir
[
  {"Jane", "1234", "sibling"},
  {"Joe", "5678", "stuff"},
  {"Job", "9012", "stuff"}
]
```

However, note that this returns a list of tuples. You can convert the tuples to lists with an additional step to map over and transform the tuples with [`Tuple.to_list/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Tuple.html#to_list/1):

```elixir
contact_details 
|> Map.values() 
|> Enum.zip() 
|> Enum.map(&Tuple.to_list/1)
```

Which yields:

```elixir
[
  ["Jane", "1234", "sibling"],
  ["Joe", "5678", "stuff"],
  ["Job", "9012", "stuff"]
]
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: A footnote about `Enum.zip/1` in Elixir: if the child lists being zipped are different lengths, it will stop when it reaches the end of the shortest list. This is consistent with implementations in some languages (e.g: Python) but not others (e.g: Ruby and some JS libraries).